# gitlab 502 error after configuring additional postgres in different path

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I have gitlab installed with default postgres db and it was working fine until I had to install another ALM tool for which postgres was bundled along with it but its installed in different path. So now I have 2 postgres setup but I have configured both of them to a different port but still I am unable to open the gitlab as I am getting 502 error with `"Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond"` .

Please find the output of the command `$sudo gitlab-ctl tail unicorn`

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:28.047856 #20275] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:28.047963 #20275] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:28.549091 #20275] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:28.549304 #20275] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (3 tries left)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:29.050605 #20275] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:29.050778 #20275] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (2 tries left)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:29.551638 #20275] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:29.551781 #20275] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (1 tries left)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:30.052684 #20275] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:30.052855 #20275] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (0 tries left)
E, [2019-09-03T17:33:30.553731 #20275] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn)

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:8080
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:164:in `bind'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:164:in `new_tcp_server'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:144:in `bind_listen'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:241:in `listen'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:851:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:851:in `each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:851:in `bind_new_listeners!'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2019-09-03_12:03:30.59723 master failed to start, check stderr log for details
2019-09-03_12:03:31.60724 failed to start a new unicorn master
2019-09-03_12:03:31.64104 starting new unicorn master


changing the default port for unicorn and gitlab
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved after i moved the another application to different port number and restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

According to the error messages, it is not the additional PostgreSQL causing problems. What port is the other application you installed listening on? I assume it's also listening on port 8080 just like GitLab Unicorn does.

```
Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Unicorn can't start because something else is listening on port 8080. You should reconfigure your other application so it listens on a different port than GitLab.

If you would rather change the Unicorn port, you can do so by adding/changing the following configuration in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

```
unicorn['port'] = 8080 # Change this to something else.
```

After this change you will need to run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

It may be beneficial for you to consider installing this new application on a new server/VM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i have already made this changes and unfortunately i can't make other application install on different server. I tried to change all the ports in gitlab.rb to different ports (other than 8080) but still i doesn't work. i am not able to find a way to make unicorn listen to different port.

Comment: Did you run reconfigure? Sometimes Unicorn does take some time to kill the old process and start the new. Look at both `/var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log` and `/var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log`. You could also run `sudo gitlab-ctl stop` and wait for all processes to stop, then start again. Run `ps -ef | grep git` and all Git processes should be stopped except svlog ones.

Comment: ~$ ps -ef | grep git
root      2727     1  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 runsvdir -P /opt/gitlab/service log: ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
root      2733  2727  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 runsv gitlab-workhor

Comment: root      2738  2727  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 runsv gitlab-monitor  
root      2742  2734  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/node- exporter  
root      2744  2735  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/unicorn  
root      2745  2739  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/logrotate

Comment: Looks good. Did you start again? Did it start on another port properly?

Comment: Yes @drew it can be closed

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can mark this answer as 'accepted' to indicate you got what you needed.